# single html form insert into multiple mysql tables with one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

So i know that this is a popular question and has a lot of responses already.However, my challenge is slightly different which has been bugging me for days now.I have an html form,which is meant to store data into multiple tables in my database.(using phpMyAdmin for now).What is a bit different is,this form allows the user to create survey questions,along with all the possible answers for that question and the preferred input type for each question and store them in mysql db.Let me show you my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title> Create a new Survey </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body style= "background: #D1D0CE">

        <h1 style= "text-align: center; font-family: Garamond; color: brown">      Create a new survey</h1><br />

            <p style="text-align:center"><img src = "logo.png"/></p>               

            <form action="insert.php"  method="post">

            <fieldset class="row1">

            <table id="formTable" class="form" >
                <tbody>
                <p style="font-family:Garamond; color:brown">
                <strong>Form Information</strong>
                </p> 
                <p>(Please enter your form details below.)</p>

                <tr>
                    <td> Form Name  :  </td><br /><br />
                    <td> <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="40"  name="formName"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date : </td><br />
                    <td> <input type="date" size="12" maxlength="40"  name="formDate"/></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
            <fieldset class="row2">
            <table id="questionTable" class="form" >

                <p style= "font-family: Garamond; color: brown">
                <strong>Question Details</strong>
                </p> 

                <p> 
                 <input type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="addRow('questionTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Question" onClick="deleteRow('questionTable')" /> 
                </p>

                    <tr>
                        <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Question : </label>
                            <input type="text" size = "16" maxlength= "50"  name="description"/>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <label>Input Type :</label>
                            <select id="widgetType" name="widgetType" required="required">
                                <option>....</option>
                                <option>radio button</option>
                                <option>check box</option>
                                <option>Edit Text</option>
                                <option>Spinner</option>
                                <option>Rating bar</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                        </p>        
                    </tr>       
            </table>

            <fieldset class="row3">
                <table id="answerTable" class="form">

                    <p style= "font-family: Garamond; color: brown">
                <strong>Answer Details</strong>
                    </p> 

                    <p> 
                 <input type="button" value="Add Answer" onClick="addAnswer('answerTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Answer" onClick="deleteAnswer('answerTable')" /> 
                        <p>(Click to add more answer options.)</p>
                    </p>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
                        <td><label>Answer : </label>  
                            <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="40"  name="answerText"></td>

                        <td>
                            <label>Match to Question :</label>
                            <select id="QuestionNumber" name="question" required="required">
                                <option>....</option>
                                <option>Question 1</option>
                                <option>Question 2</option>
                                <option>Question 3</option>
                                <option>Question 4</option>
                                <option>Question 5</option>
                                <option>Question 6</option>
                                <option>Question 7</option>
                                <option>Question 8</option>
                                <option>Question 9</option>
                                <option>Question 10</option>

                            </select>


                        </td>   
                        </p>
                    </tr>

                </table>



            <fieldset class="row4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

        </body>



</html>
```

And the php part:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $host = "localhost"; // host of MySQL server
        $user = "root"; // MySQL user
        $pwd = ""; // MySQL user's password
        $db  = "webservice";  // database name

        // Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd , $db);

        // Check connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
            die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO form (title,date) VALUES ('".$_POST['formName']."','".$_POST['formDate']."')";


        mysqli_query($con , $sql);





        mysqli_close($con) ;
    }   
?>
```

So in my db,i have a the following structure :

1. Form table

   ```
   -form_id(PK, AI)

   -tile

   -date
   ```
2. questions table

   ```
   -question_id(PK, AI)

   -description

   -form_id(FK) references form_id in form table
   ```
3. answers table

   ```
   -answer_id(PK, AI)

   -answer_text

   -question_id(FK) references question_id from questions
   ```
4. widgets (stores the different widgets/input type chosen from form(radio,text area etc).)

   ```
   -widget_id(PK,AI)

   -widget_type

   -question_id(FK) references question_id from questions
   ```

   Each question can have more than one answer but only one widget type.Each answer can only have one question and so can the widgets.So a single question_id may appear many times in answers table.This is where i get stuck:

   - Creating the form properly to achieve this.The questions and all it's possible answers      are sort of dynamic.So you can decide to add questions and input fields for answers as you go.
   - I can dynamically add more questions and more answers,but can't seem to figure out how to link each answer to it's question.
   - I'm also having a challenge writing a proper query that will insert the question_id into the questions table and all the related foreign keys where it's referenced as well.

   I would really appreciate some pointers so i can head in the right direction.Really sorry for the long question.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's good news and some bad news.

The bad news is, you can't insert into multiple tables in 100% sql.

The good news is, you can do it in several steps.

When you insert your core record, you can do another sql query

```
$getid = mysql_query("SELECT last_insert_id()");
$getid = mysql_fetch_array($getid);
$id = $getid[0];
```

Then you can use the return from this result for all future inserts, eg:

```
"INSERT into answers (answer_text, question_id) values ('Some text', " . $id . ")"
```

The catch is it's best to insert all answers to the question at once, and then move on to the next question.

If they are adding extra answers to an existing  from, you will need to get the question_id from somewhere so the above script will work.

Comment: Hi @Joel Small. Thank you so much for the quick response.Do you mind explaining your code snippet a little bit.Just so i can understand where it goes.From the little i can get, it's like we're storing the primary key value in the $getid variable.Then i don't get why we:re using an array there.How about a case where 5 answers all belong to the same que? How do we handle that in the query?

Comment: Admittedly, my answer uses the mysql functions and not mysqli, so the implementation may be slightly different.  I'd recommend using @Mayank 's solution.

Comment: Following on ... I'd recommend using @Mayank 's solution.  On to my code, the mysql_fetch_array() gets an array of values for that mysql row, where the first column is at index 0.  There's only one value in this row.  I assigned it to $id for neatness only.  Updating my answer with more detailed explanation now

Comment: So would it be proper for me to follow your example but instead of last_insert_id() i just replace it with mysqli_insert_id() ? Because for now, this is the edit i made following both  you and @Mayank 's advice : $sql = "INSERT INTO form (title,date) VALUES ('".$_POST['formName']."','".$_POST['formDate']."')";
  mysqli_query($con , $sql);
  
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO questions (description, form_id) VALUES ('".$_POST['description']."', mysqli_insert_id())"; this only inserts into the form table and i get nothing on the questions table.neither description nor the form_id from the mysqli_insert_id()

Comment: Correct, you still have to do individual inserts for all subsequent tables, but you can do this because you now have the primary key from the core table 'forms'

Comment: Thanks @Joel Small.i wanted to mark this as answer but it says i have to have a reputation of at least 15 and above.

Comment: No worries @naffie, don't forget about me when you're famous!

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the PK genrated for your insert queries
Refer manaual : https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id 
`last_insert_id()` is not a recommended method as it fails to give proper id in case of simultaneous insertions....

Comment: Thank you @Mayank for that pointer.I've also checked out other threads and i see what you mean by avoiding last_insert_id().A quick question though,won't mysqli_insert_id() be inconsistent when it comes to a question with multiple answers?because from the link you posted,it returns the value of the last id that was inserted.So what if the next answer still refers to the previous id? how can i modify my query to cater for that?

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` will only return PK for the current insert and never the last insert id, so when you insert a new answer for a question, you'll get PK of the answer tuple inserted.....to map it correctly, you'll have to pass the PK of the question it has been answered for in your `mysqli_query` as the FK as per your schema......

Comment: Thank you @ Mayank. Both of your answers were really helpful. Unfortunately i cannot mark any of them because i do not have a reputation of at least 15